# Python/Pandas: Figuring out the source of SettingWithCopyWarning in a Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Cannot find out the source of SettingWithCopyWarning? I tried to fix the assignment operations as suggested in the documentation but still, it gives me the SettingWithCopyWarning. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def fuzzy_merge(df_left, df_right, key_left, key_right, threshold=84, limit=1):
    """
    df_1: the left table to join
    df_2: the right table to join
    key_left: the key column of the left table
    key_right: the key column of the right table
    threshold: how close the matches should be to return a match, based on Levenshtein distance
    limit: the amount of matches that will get returned, these are sorted high to low
    """
    s = df_right.loc[:, key_right].tolist()

    m = df_left.loc[:, key_left].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s, limit=limit))
    df_left.loc[:, "matches"] = m

    m2 = df_left.loc[:, "matches"].apply(
        lambda x: ", ".join([i[0] for i in x if i[1] >= threshold])
    )

    df_left.loc[:, "matches"] = m2
    return df_left
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `.copy()` in some places? For example `df_left.loc[:, "matches"] = m2.copy()`

Comment: @Let'stry I tried to use the copy(). But I still get the warning. Thought the code runs and does what is suppose to do. But I can't figure out the source of these warnings.

Comment: Did you tried it in every line? Another option is to debug (if you can do it) or to remove everything and add and execute code line by line until you get the warning. With this at least you can know which line is causing the problem.

Comment: fixed it using the this operation: ```new_df_left = df_left.assign(matches=m)```